# Cronjob script won't pass in mysql password

Tags: mysql, cron

I have a script called /etc/cron.daily/99loganalyzer_expire, which is as so:

```
#!/bin/bash
SQL="DELETE FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY)"   
MYSQL_USER="loganalyzer"
MYSQL_PASS="loganalyzerpassword"
MYSQL_DB="Syslog"    
echo $SQL | /usr/bin/mysql --user=$MYSQL_USER --password=$MYSQL_PASS $MYSQL_DB
```

When it runs overnight, I get an email saying it failed:

```
/etc/cron.daily/99loganalyzer-expire:

ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'loganalyzer'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

...however, when I run it as root from the console, it works:

```
# time /etc/cron.daily/99loganalyzer-expire

real    1m16.391s
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.008s
```

How can I pass in the credentials for this mysql user so they will work in a cronjob?

Comment: append `> /tmp/loganalyzer.log 2>&1` to the end of line to see what happens.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Putting login credentials into a command line like this is risky, as anyone who can view the process list could view those credentials.  A better option is to put those credentials into an option file such as ~/.my.cnf and then reference that file in your command.

```
[client]
user="loganalyzer"
password="loganalyzerpassword"
```

Make sure to chmod the permissions to 0600 on that options file to prevent it from being viewable by anyone except the owner. Then your mysql command would be:

```
echo $SQL | /usr/bin/mysql --defaults-file=/root/.my.cnf Syslog
```

More details on option files can be found at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/option-files.html.

Comment: This is, indeed, a better way to do it (I'm already using it for my Mysql backup process).  Don't know why I didn't do it myself.  It works through regular cron, I'll mark this as correct if it runs out of cron.daily correctly.

Comment: Another reason to use ~/.my.cnf : When password changes, you just have to update 1 file, not a bunch of crontab/scripts (Murphy said your coworkers will always forget to update one entry : The script that performs backups).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a different command.

Something like this should work:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -uUSERNAME -pPASSWORD -e "DELETE FROM SystemEvents WHERE ReceivedAt < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(),INTERVAL 30 DAY);" syslog
```

Might need to be adapted for your needs, and I am not 100% sure how the DB is selected.

Comment: The problem appears to be the password getting recognized, not the command getting executed.  How does changing the invocation (from `--password=$foo` to `-p$foo` change that?

Comment: Hard to tell - but I know that a command like that works in a cron. Might have something to do with you echoing it through a pipe - I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

The order is wrong, the last line, what is before the pipe should be at the end of the line.

I mean, the SQL command is the last bit.

Comment: What exactly is wrong? This doesn't address that the same file works when invoked from the shell.